# Como dar stop em uma função através do console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de stopar um fadeIn() durante sua execução de modo que a tela fique exatamente como estava no momento que eu parei.

O ideal seria algo genérico, que funcione para fadeIn, slideUp, slideDown, setTimeout etc.

É possivel fazer isso utilizando o console do navegador? Como seria?

OBS: Só para informação, quero fazer isso para poder pegar o css do item no momento da transição, pois é um componente e ele muda as classes e consequentemente o css...

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "seu-elemento" ).stop();
```

Esse método serve para parar animações em geral.

[.stop() | API jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Exemplo retirado do jQuery:

```js
// Start animation
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).animate({ left: "+=100px" }, 2000 );
});
 
// Stop animation when button is clicked
$( "#stop" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).stop();
});
 
// Start animation in the opposite direction
$( "#back" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).animate({ left: "-=100px" }, 2000 );
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>stop demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #abc;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<button id="go">Go</button>
<button id="stop">STOP!</button>
<button id="back">Back</button>
<div class="block"></div>
 
</body>
</html>
```